# Parser Error:Only assignment, call, increment, etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

so I was reading the unity 3d script reference. Link below
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

I wanted to test the example

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform explosionPrefab;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        ContactPoint contact = collision.contacts[0];
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, contact.normal);
        Vector3 pos = contact.point;
        Instantiate(explosionPrefab, pos, rot) as Transform;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

but I receive the error

Parse error: Only assignments, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object

at line 20[Instantiate(explosionPrefab, pos, rot) as Transform;]

Could someone please explain to me why I get such an error? and how I could fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Consider searching for error message/error code to find explanation on MSDN. [CS0201](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx) - explains the issue and shows most common case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
Transform transform = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, pos, rot) as Transform;
```

Alternatively remove the as Transform part if you don't need the instance

```
Instantiate(explosionPrefab, pos, rot)
```